# Gulp. Browsersync. При вызове метода browsersync.reload({stream: true}) страница не обновляется

Tags: javascript, gulp, browsersync

**Всякий раз когда обновляю файл срабатывает watch, но browsersync не обновляет страницу**

gulpfile.js

```
function serve() {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./" + distPath
    }
  });
}

function html() {
  return src(path.src.html, {base: srcPath})
    .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
    .pipe(browsersync.reload({stream: true}));
}

function watchFiles() {
  gulp.watch([path.watch.html], html);
}

const build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(html, ...)); //точки вместо методов подобных до html()
const watch = gulp.series(build, gulp.parallel(watchFiles, serve));

exports.watch = watch;
```

*это фрагмент gulpfile.js остальные методы это css, js, images, ... которые выполняют тоже самое что и html()*

terminal

```
$ gulp watch
[17:14:33] Using gulpfile ~/.../gulpfile.js
[17:14:33] Starting 'watch'...
[17:14:33] Starting 'clean'...
[17:14:33] Finished 'clean' after 24 ms
[17:14:33] Starting 'html'...
[17:14:33] Finished 'html' after 582 ms
[17:14:33] Starting 'watchFiles'...
[17:14:33] Starting 'serve'...
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ---------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.31.231:3000
 ---------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 ---------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./dist/
[17:14:43] Starting 'html'...
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (index.html)
[17:14:43] Finished 'html' after 31 ms
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
[17:14:47] Starting 'html'...
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (index.html)
[17:14:47] Finished 'html' after 25 ms
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
[17:14:48] Starting 'html'...
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (index.html)
[17:14:48] Finished 'html' after 32 ms
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
```

*Хоть терминал и выдает сообщение о том что страница перезагружается - но этого не происходит*

Comment: Попробывал подключать browsersync отдельно, через консоль, но результат один - пишет что страница перезагужается, но нет. Может ли браузер блокировать перезагрузку? (macOS chrome)

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле ответ очень прост, на странице должен быть тег `<body>`, то есть browser-sync не может обновлять страницу пока этого тега не будет.